# How do I add emails from a Google sheet to be invitees on a Google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the script I have now, taken directly from the video. It works to schedule the event. What I am trying to do though is to have cells in another column, that would contain emails, be automatically added to this event. Further, if at all possible, could I have a meeting link (Zoom, Teams, etc) in another cell to add that to the description?

'''

```
function scheduleFastStart() {
 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);



  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A9:C10").getValues();
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

    var shift = signups[x];

    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var newHire = shift[2];

    eventCal.createEvent(newHire, startTime, endTime);
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
    .addItem('Schedule Fast Start Now', 'scheduleFastStart')
    .addToUi();
}
```

'''

I'd really appreciate any help here. I did see a similar post but to be honest it was way out of my league to even attempt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the attendees email, while I can see that you already know how to read it and extract the value, then you only need to update your [`Calendar.createEvent(…,…,…)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime) to [`Calendar.createEvent(…,…,…,…)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options). The new method has one extra parameter compared to your current one. That extra parameter is called `options` and can be used to declare the `guests` list, event `location`, `description` and whether to send invitations or not. You can see some examples on the linked docs. Please ask me any extra doubts about this procedure.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me to figure it out. I appreciate the help!